# How to download CDF player 11.2?

Tags: cdfplayer

For last 24 hrs, not able to make progress on this. I just want to download the CDF player for 11.2.

I am on windows 7, 64 bit, home edition.

I followed the instructions here https://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/.  Selected latest version. Downloaded `CDFPlayer_11.2.0_WIN_DM.exe` with no problem.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Next, double clicked on it. I see a little icon shows up in the task bar on window, and then nothing happens. It just sits there doing nothing. I also tried running it as administrator.

According to http://support.wolfram.com/kb/8075 after clicking on the .exe file, it says

> The Download Manager opens and immediately begins downloading CDF
>   Player’s installation files to your Downloads folder.

This never happens on my PC. The download manager never shows up. After waiting for long time (may be 1 hr or so) this message shows up

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I rebooted the PC. Did not help.

How can one find out what is the problem? Is Wolfram servers down at this moment and that is why CDF player is not downloading? Task manager just shows the CDF manager running but not doing anything. CPU not changing.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any one else having same trouble? Why is it not working? I never had such problem before.  This download manager seems to be new feature that WRI added. Before, one would just download the full 1 GB .exe right away. Now it seems they replaced this with a small download manager which is then used to download the actual player.

Comment: Maybe the problem is related to your firewall/anti-virus settings?

Comment: @K.J. may be. But I had the same antivirus software for 15 years now (ESET) and never had problem like this.  But If there is such an issue, then WRI documentation should mention it? And others would have seen it also. I am sure I am not only one using anti-virus software. I do not have any special firewall installed myself. Unless windows 7 itself has something. Same PC for 5 years now.